# Managing HTTP response in Angular 6

Tags: angular, httpclient

*Context of my problem* :

I am trying to create an array of the google maps Longitude and Latitudes to use in a heatmap. I am able to get data from my localhost and want to be able to reference an array that I create within the subscribe function outside of the function.

When I console.log a all of my data it comes out perfectly. When I try to reference the this.heatmapData outside of the subscribe function it is empty.

Here is the code

```
    this.result = this.examsApi.getExams()
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.examsList = data;
          this.i=0;
          var obj = JSON.parse(data);
          var val;
          this.heatmapData = [];
          for (val in obj["index"]) {
            console.log(this.heatmapData) // Fills perfectly
            this.heatmapData.push(new google.maps.LatLng(obj["Latitude"][val], obj["Longitude"][val])); // The parameters are filled with longitude and latitude values a http.get request in another file.
      } 
        });
    console.log(this.heatmapData) // Becomes empty
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 3):

**It does not become empty but it is empty at the moment of logging**, you log it into the console, and then you fetch the data - subscribe is async!

Order of execution:

1. Create cold observable by `this.examsApi.getExams()`
2. Heat it up by subscribing to it - AJAX request is STARTED
3. `console.log(this.heatmapData)` // prints empty array because IT IS EMPTY NOW
4. IO delay
5. AJAX FINISHES - Response comes, subscription callback is called - you push data to `this.heatmapData`

I can only assume that you see no update on UI. This is because you are pushing to the array - Angular will not detect such change by itself. Either you have to invoce change detection run, or better, create new array, but data to it, and **replace the array** by assigning `this.heatmapData=yourNewArrayOfData`

> and want to be able to reference an array that I create within the
>   subscribe function outside of the function.

Looks like I got to the point here - build new array and assign it to `this.heatmapData` insteed of pushing. Angular will detect that change.

Since some people finds this answer "not an answer at all" i must include copy-pasted code I guess.

```
   this.result = this.examsApi.getExams()
            .subscribe(data => {
              this.examsList = data;
              this.i=0;
              var obj = JSON.parse(data);
              var val;
              const newData= [];
              for (val in obj["index"]) {
                newData.push(new google.maps.LatLng(obj["Latitude"][val], obj["Longitude"][val])); // The parameters are filled with longitude and latitude values a http.get request in another file.
          } 
          this.heatmapData=newData; // this will do the trick
          console.log(this.heatmapData); // this will print just fine
            });
```

Comment: Explanation what is happening is the solution to all OPs problems here - not only ths particular one, but any similar issue he will face when debuging async code in the future.

Comment: Thanks Antonios. This helped me realize the concept. You can't globalize or make public outside of the subscribe function any of the "this." variables